# Can I ask a question about lightroom running slow?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am having an issue with lightroom where it seems to lag tremendously when lightroom is maximized (I have a 25" screen) but when I shrink lightroom down to maybe like 15% of my screen it runs smoothly.

Would that be an acceptable question for the photography stack exchange?

Comment: I'd probably suggest Super User and I suspect a variant of your question has been asked before... http://superuser.com/search?q=lightroom+is%3Aquestion

Answer (score 2):

Questions about post-processing are fine.

Questions about malfunctioning post-processing software are not fine. You'd better direct them to SuperUser.com